# set some consecutive bits in a byte

Tags: c#, byte, bit-manipulation, bit

I need an efficient method with the following signature:

```
public byte SetBits(byte oldValue, byte newValue, int startBit, int bitCount)
```

Which returns `oldValue`, only that starting from its `startbit` bit up to its `startbit + bitcount` bit (zero-based), it's replaced with the first `bitcount` bits of `newValue`

For example, if:

- `oldValue = 11101101`
- `newValue = 10000011`
- `startBit = 1`
- `bitCount = 2`

Then the result would be: `11101111` (the segment `10` in `oldValue` is replaced with the corresponding `11` segment in `newValue`)

Comment: btw void method returning a byte is really cool ;) [no offense :)]

Comment: I just got done with a 12 hour kernel debugging session so I hope my code can help you :)

Comment: By debugging I mean yelling at the monitor whenever the kernel hangs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go... Bitshift both directions to get the mask... then use it to generate the new byte

```
public static byte SetBits(byte oldValue, byte newValue, int startBit, int bitCount)
{
    if (startBit < 0 || startBit > 7 || bitCount < 0 || bitCount > 7 
                     || startBit + bitCount > 8)
        throw new OverflowException();

    int mask = (255 >> 8 - bitCount) << startBit;
    return Convert.ToByte((oldValue & (~mask)) | ((newValue << startBit) & mask));
}
```

Comment: Currently too dumbfounded by highmem errors to write something like this. GJ

Comment: Thanks, this looks similar to what I ended up doing, only more efficient (just like I predicted) - will accept as soon as I test your solution

Comment: OK, I needed to make some small modifications (I've edited your answer accordingly) and now it works well

Comment: @ohadsc Ahh... 0 indexed from right side... my implementation was from left side. Glad you adapted it to your needs.

Comment: @deepee1, wait, you really indexed your bit numbers from the left (most-significant) side??

Answer (score 0):

```
startBit--; //account for 0 indexing
byte flag = 1 << startBit;
for (int i = startBit; i < bitCount; i++, flag <<= 1)
{
    byte mask = newValue & flag;
    if (mask != 0)
        oldValue |= mask;
    else
        oldValue &= ~(flag);
}
return oldValue;
```

Some brain compiled code here but it should be along the lines that you want if I read the question correctly.

Comment: |= would not zero ones in oldValue

Comment: Thanks for catching that, will fix :)

Comment: `flag` doesn't change during each invocation.  You'd have to make `flag` a delegate and `1 << startBit` a lambda for this to work.  Or add `flag = 1 << startBit` to the third `for` loop clause.  Also, due to the `&=` operating one bit at a time, I think you'd clear out `oldValue` after two iterations through the loop.

Comment: Woops I see what you mean, I accidentally put startBit <<= 1 instead of flag, my bad

Comment: @Jesus: I still think you're going to nearly always get `0` for oldValue at the end.  For example, first you mask against `0001000`, then against `0010000`.  I think you need to build your mask in the loop, *then* apply the mask.  Also, I don't think a triple-`&` is going to work, either, if you're trying to *replace* those bits.  You probably want to mask `oldValue`, reverse-mask `newValue`, and `|` the results together.

Comment: @Merlyn, Yeah you're right maybe I shouldn't code after work haha I'll fix it now.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, I think this is what you are after:

```
byte mask = 0xFF;
for (int i = startPos-1; i < numBits; i++)
{
     if ((newValue & (1 << i)) == 1)
     {
          mask = (byte)(mask | (1 << i));
     }
     else
     {
          mask = (byte)(mask &~(1<<i));
     }
 }
 return (byte)(oldValue & mask);
```

This code is based on some neat tricks from [Low Level Bit Hacks You Absolutely Must Know](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/low-level-bit-hacks-you-absolutely-must-know/)

I know setting a bit in a byte initialized to 0xFF is really a no-op, but I felt the code should be left in as it can help show off what is really going on. I encourage users of the code to optimize it as needed.